# buffered reader .. improper output

Tags: java, file

I have a code which displays the content of a file. I tried to do that using 2 different ways.. However, i didnt got the answer using first way, while i got the answer using second way.   i want to know y the ans is not coming in first case?
in first case i used a while loop to check whether my file is not empty...i dont get the output of my file...in second case i pass the same while loop using function and i get the result

```
                line++;

            } 

 l = line;
        System.out.println("lines are "+ l);
    String[] text =new String[l];

 for(i=0;i<l;i++)
    {
        text[i]=b.readLine();//Reads a line of text
        System.out.println("text is "+text[i]);
        //System.out.print("txt "+ text[i]);
       }

        return null;

}

    }
```

Output:=
lines are 4
text is null
text is null
text is null
text is null

Code 2--

```
public class JavaApplication9 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // TODO code application logic here
 new FileReader(path);ception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ReadMe.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ReadMe.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } return ln;
}

    }
```

Output--
line 4
I am getting the contents of my file here

Comment: So whats your question again?

Comment: i want to know y the ans is not coming in first case?

Comment: Please format your illegible code.

Comment: in first case i used a while loop to check whether my file is not empty...i dont get the output of my file...in second case i pass the same while loop using function and i get the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, for #1, you've got nulls because

```
while((lin=b.readLine())!=null)
{   
   line++;
}
```

consumed all you inputstream. When you've tried

```
text[i]=b.readLine();
```

your reader was already in the end of the file, so there was nothing more to be read.

For #2, you're declaring two FileReaders, one inside and another outside rlh. That's why it seems to work.

Comment: you should instantiate new FileReader and BufferedReader before the for loop. And also, don't forget to close these readers. If you use a dynamic structure such a List instead of an array, you don't have to know the number of lines before actually storing the data.

Answer (score 0):

In your first example you are reading the file until readLine() returns null, which means you are at end of file (EOF), then you keep reading it, and you're surprised that readLine() continues to return null, which continues to mean that you continue to be at EOF. Don't be surprised at this.

In your second example you are opening the file twice, once to count the lines, and once to read them.

Both are examples of poor practice. Instead of an array, which commits you to knowing the line count in advice, you should use a List of some form to hold the lines. In fact what you should really be doing is processing the file a line at a time, instead of reading it all into memory at all, which doesn't scale to large files, and adds latency.

Answer (score -1):

The correct way to use `BufferedReader` for file reading ...

```
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("filepath")));
    String s;
    while( (s=br.readLine()) != null ){
        //  process your string like ... 
        System.out.println(s);
    }
```

Comment: Doesn't answer the question as to why the two programs differ.